# Sum inside cast function in Mysql gives error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Amount) > 0  THEN CONCAT(CAST((SUM(Amount) AS VARCHAR(20) ) , ' Cr') 
                WHEN SUM(Amount) < 0  THEN CONCAT(CAST(ABS(SUM(Amount)) AS VARCHAR(20) ) , ' Dr') 
                ELSE '0.00'
           END 
     FROM  amount_transactions 
    WHERE Account_ID = 1 ;
```

It gives me an error.INVALID syntax.

Comment: Which error can you include error details ?

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(20) ) , ' Cr') 
            WHEN SUM(Amount) < 0  THEN CONCAT(CAST((ABS(' at line 1

Comment: You don't need to cast explicitly. But when you do - use `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: It gives me an error.INVALID syntax. - because your bracketing is wrong and you are not allowed to cast to varchar see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html for type values permitted in cast,

Comment: It worked when I used CHAR instead of VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could minimize your query as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Amount) > 0  
                THEN CONCAT(SUM(Amount) , ' Cr') 
            WHEN SUM(Amount) < 0  
                THEN CONCAT(ABS(SUM(Amount)), ' Dr') 
            ELSE '0.00'
       END 
FROM  amount_transactions 
WHERE Account_ID = 1 ;
```

If you really need to [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) your value you can use [CHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) instead of varchar